# R: find difference if at least one of the two values are zero

Tags: r, diff

I would like to calculate the abs(difference) of rows (current with preceding row), if at least one of the values is zero. If both values are non-zeros, it should return 0.

Example: the column 'A' shows the initial data, 'Diff' shows what I want to get:

```
df <- data.frame(A=c(0,0,1,2,3,4,0,0),Diff=c(0,0,1,0,0,0,4,0))
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way using the **`dplyr`** package and the `lag` function:

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- data.frame(A=c(0,0,1,2,3,4,0,0),Diff=c(0,0,1,0,0,0,4,0))
df1 %>%
    mutate(lag_A = lag(A),
           Diff2 = abs(A - lag_A)) %>%
    mutate(Diff2 = ifelse(is.na(lag_A), 0,
                  ifelse(A == 0 | lag_A == 0, Diff2, 0)))

  A Diff lag_A Diff2
1 0    0    NA     0
2 0    0     0     0
3 1    1     0     1
4 2    0     1     0
5 3    0     2     0
6 4    0     3     0
7 0    4     4     4
8 0    0     0     0
```

You could then use the `select` function to grab the columns you want. I left all of the columns in the table to illustrate the solution.

Answer (score 0):

### Assumption

I'm gonna assume the first value of Diff is not the result of the operation you want, **because the first value of A has no preceding value**, therefore i chose to repeat it on the answer, but you can add anything instead of `A[1]`.

Edit: I also assumed you wanted a solution using only base, otherwise, bouncyball's solution works like a charm.

### Solution

```
Diff = rep(0,(length(A)-1))
Diff[which(mapply(xor,A[-1],A[-length(A)]))] = abs(A[-1][which(mapply(xor,A[-1],A[-length(A)]))]-A[-length(A)][which(mapply(xor,A[-1],A[-length(A)]))])
Diff = c(A[1],Diff)
```

You can improve upon this by making it a named function like this:

```
foo = function(A){
    Diff = rep(0,(length(A)-1))
    Diff[which(mapply(xor,A[-1],A[-length(A)]))] = abs(A[-1][which(mapply(xor,A[-1],A[-length(A)]))]-A[-length(A)][which(mapply(xor,A[-1],A[-length(A)]))])
    Diff = c(A[1],Diff)
    Diff
}
```

### Explanation

Instead of operating A, we use:
`A[-1]`, which yields `0 1 2 3 4 0 0` (equal to A but without the first element)
and `A[-length(A)]`, which yields: `0 0 1 2 3 4 0` (equal to A, but without the last element).

If we subtract the first from the latter we have the element-wise subtractions right, but we still need to know **when** these subtractions need to occur.

By combining functions [xor](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.4.0/topics/Logic), [mapply](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.4.0/topics/mapply) and [which](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.4.0/topics/which) (all of them are members of base), like this:

`which(mapply(xor,A[-1],A[-length(A)]))` we find:

`2 6` which are the indexes of the positions in A[-1] and A[-length(A)] where subtractions should happen.

Now we create a 0 vector called Diff the same size of our new vectors using:

`Diff = rep(0,length(A)-1)`, then we change only the indexes that should not contain 0s using:

`Diff[which(mapply(xor,A[-1],A[-length(A)]))] = abs(A[-1][which(mapply(xor,A[-1],A[-length(A)]))]-A[-length(A)][which(mapply(xor,A[-1],A[-length(A)]))])`

And finally we put back the first element again using `Diff = c(A[1],Diff)`.

Comment: I forgot that OP was using 'Diff' instead of diff, edited.